# Error binding properties in VB WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dependency-properties

I'm trying to create a wpf library and there's a problem I can't find the solution for.

First I have this control

```
<UserControl x:Class="UnitSelectionBox">
[Omitting for size reasons]

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ComboBox x:Name="UnitList"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                   AncestorType={x:Type local:UnitSelectionBox}},
                             Path=Dimension,
                             Converter={StaticResource converterDimension},
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                             Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                    AncestorType={x:Type local:UnitSelectionBox}},
                             Path=Unit,
                             Converter={StaticResource converterUnit},
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                             Mode=TwoWay}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
</Grid>
```

This works like a charm when I'm binding its properties. It updates internal properties whenever I change the combo box and vice versa. The problem is when I try to use by `UnitSelectionBox` inside another control where I would like to bind the Unit property.

```
<local:UnitSelectionBox 
    x:Name="UnitBox"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Unit="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:QuantityBox}},
    Path=Unit, 
    Mode=TwoWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

I get the error `A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject`.

I can get through this error registering the properties:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly UnitProperty As DependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Unit",
                                GetType(Unit),
                                GetType(UnitSelectionBox),
                                New PropertyMetadata(Dimensionless.SI.ToUnit))

Public Shared ReadOnly DimensionProperty As DependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Dimension",
                                GetType(IDimension),
                                GetType(UnitSelectionBox),
                                New PropertyMetadata(New Dimensionless))
```

But when I do this, the `UnitSelectionBox` stops updating its values.
Again, the `UnitSelectionBox` works when I use it alone, but I can't bind its properties to another control. If it's not with `DependencyProperty` how can I Bind its properties in another control?

---

UPDATE:

The code that holds both properties in `UnitSelectionBox` is

```
Private P_Unit As Unit = Dimensionless.SI.ToUnit

Property Dimension As IDimension
    Get
        Return P_Unit.Dimension
    End Get
    Set(value As IDimension)
        NotifyPropertyChanging("Dimension")
        Unit = value.SI
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Dimension")
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Unit() As Unit
    Get
        Return P_Unit
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Unit)
        NotifyPropertyChanging("Unit")
        P_Unit = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Unit")
    End Set
End Property
```

The XAML of the control trying to bind its property with `UnitSelectionBox` and return the Binding to dependency property error that I'm using is:

```
<local:UnitSelectionBox 
        x:Name="UnitBox"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Unit="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:QuantityBox}},
                       Path=Unit, 
                       Mode=TwoWay, 
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

---

I'm using a WPF app to test the control that uses the following code:

```
  <ProtoControls:UnitSelectionBox
        Name="UnBox" 
        Dimension="{StaticResource dimensionT}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="11" Margin="162,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36"/>
    <Button Content="Unit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ButtonUnit_Click"/>
```

The sub run by the button is:

```
Private Sub ButtonUnit_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    MsgBox(UnBox.Unit.Name)
End Sub
```

The result I expect and the one I get when not using DependencyProperty is
[IMG without dependency property](https://image.ibb.co/mSzjdG/without_dependency_property.png)

But when I add the DependencyProperty part for the Unit I get
[IMG with unit dependency property](https://image.ibb.co/b80J5w/with_dependency_property_unit.png)

Adding dependency property for both Dimension and Unit I get
[IMG with both dependency property](https://image.ibb.co/nLmrQw/with_dependency_property_both.png)

Comment: 1) Are you saying that when you got the error, `Unit` was defined as a regular C# property, not a dependency property? 2) Can you explain exactly, in visual terms, what is different on the screen in front of you when "stops updating it's values"? Please answer both questions, thanks.

Comment: 3) How are you using `Unit` and `Dimension` *inside* the XAML for your UserControl? Are you doing anything with them at all?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have a WPF app to test my controls, this app has a button that access internal property of UnitSelectionBox. So when I'm not using any DependencyProperty part of the code, I have the expected behaviour:
[IMG without dependency properties](https://ibb.co/jGoMQw)
If I remove only the unit part of the dependency property, it uses the correct dimension but won't change with the combobox selected item:
[IMG with unit dependency property](https://ibb.co/nKJ5kw)
And finally if I use both, I can't get any results but the initial values:
[IMG using both](https://ibb.co/hZGEdG)

Comment: OK, you have a box that says "Kelvin". What does that have to do with any of your code, or any of your problems? I haven't seen the rest of your code. **Please answer the other two questions as well.**

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, when I remove the DependencyProperty part of the code, the control behaves as I expected, but I can't bind it's properties in another control.

Comment: Good luck with your problem.

Comment: Do you have the Dimension property on your user control (that is 2nd code block in your question, you don't have it there) set and bound? That's where ComboBox's ItemsSource will be looking.

Comment: @djomlastic Yes, that's why I have a list of options for units, in the shown test case Temperature units. I think if I didn't have that it wouldn't work in any case, am I right?

Comment: You need DependencyProperties for both. If your Dimension is also bound to QuantityBox (or wherever it should be), I can only suggest that you set null values for your DependencyProperty defaults (object instances are rarely set as defaults for DPs, and your bindings might be broken but you could be picking that "unit" string from your default object).

Comment: @djomlastic If I don't set any dependence property default doesn't help, it isn't binding anyway. It's like when I set the dependency property the internal properties seize to exist, and what is bounded is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that I'm using incorrectly the dependency property. In order to access property and bind it I should have changed the access to Unit and Dimension properties like this.

```
Property Dimension As IDimension
    Get
        Return GetValue(UnitProperty).Dimension
    End Get
    Set(value As IDimension)
        NotifyPropertyChanging("Dimension")
        SetValue(UnitProperty, value.SI)
        SetValue(DimensionProperty, value)
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Dimension")
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Unit() As Unit
    Get
        Return GetValue(UnitProperty)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Unit)
        NotifyPropertyChanging("Unit")
        SetValue(UnitProperty, value)
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Unit")
    End Set
End Property
```

Using the GetValue and SetValue methods defined by the dependency object instead of the internal fields.